# Application.Ontime is not running at the set time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather odd problem. I am using `Application.Ontime TimeValue()` to run excel macro at given time (refresh some data and send an email). It used to work great until 3 weeks ago but since, the macro are executed at `"random time"`, i.e with some delay from 1 to 30 minutes.

I tried on 2 computers with up to date windows and `Excel 365` versions. Issues are the same. All macro run well when I execute them manually or without the `Application.Ontime TimeValue()`.

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:00:00"), "Update"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:03:00"), "SendPDF"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:04:00"), "SaveThisWorkbook"
```

As said before, I have no error message and the `Application. OnTime` add some random delay to the execution.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure there is no other code running in the same Excel instance when the scheduled time arrives?

Comment: @JB3872 does `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "Update"` Work for you ?

Comment: @Dorian Yes, it works on the computer in a "simple" excel file that does only that.

Comment: @jkpieterse It is probably something like that. There is no other code running at the same time. The macro is very simple and run well if I remove the Application .Ontime (i.e If I run all routines at the same time). Any idea what could prevent to run Application.Ontime?

Comment: issue with your clock ? is the computer time correct ?

Comment: _Any idea what could prevent to run Application.Ontime?_ Application needs to be in _Ready_ mode to execute scheduled code. Operations like: editing cell, opening modal dialog will prevent running schedued code.

Comment: Any other VBA code that is running will also delay the start of the timed procedure.